# How execute POST in a cURL command to upload a file

Tags: java, web-services, rest, unix, curl

I made the method to upload a file using a RestFul server by a web and copy the field I selected to a folder but when I try to use the same method by the command cUrl don't run, I think is the syntax maybe or how I pass the params to the method.

Here is the method:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

    logger.debug(message);
    String uploadedFileLocation = C_HOME_TEST + fileDetail.getFileName();

    // save it
    writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);
    String output = "File " + fileDetail.getFileName() + " uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;
    saveInFile(fileDetail.getFileName());
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
```

and here is the command:

```
curl  --form "fileupload=@filename.png" http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/file
```

If I make the GET from this class connect without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

The command was wrong

```
curl -X POST -F 'file=@apple.png' http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/file
```

Answer (score -1):

Command:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' -v -F 'file=@/path/to/theFile' http://localhost:35681/api
```

Parameter explanation:

```
-H  --header <header/@file>  Pass custom header(s) to server
-v  --verbose                Make the operation more talkative
-F  --form <name=content>    Specify multipart MIME data
```

For more details, you can check the `curl` documentation via `curl --help` on the terminal.

Comment: anyone can just check "Curl -help" all the option still I will mention all the action